# Using DictField with html post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some code that used to work before the Drf 3.3 / Django 1.8 combo:

I'd have a serializer like this:

```
class MySerializer(...):
   dict_field = serializers.DictField(child=serializers.CharField())
   .....
```

The following used to work previously, but now dict field is empty:

```
curl http://server.com/api/endpoint -H "Authorization: Token <XXX>" -d other_field=ABC -d dict_field.key1=val1 -d dict_field.key2=val2
```

The code for DictField seems like it expects the data in this format, but it's not working. Other non dict fields work, and using json works, but for separate reasons, I must use HTTP POST. Is this a bug with the latest versions?

Answer (score 1):

you can post dictionary data like :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token <XXX>" -X POST http://server.com/api/endpoint -d '{"other_field": "ABC","dict_field": {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason (legacy clients), I must use HTML POST (text/html)  ... this seems to be a regression that was introduced in the 2.3.4 version. I've posted the comment/issue to the github repo. Thanks.